# Is there an equivalent of C#'s nameof(..) in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I have the following lines of code I want to port from C# to F#:

```
private const string TypeName = nameof(MyClass);
private const string MemberName = nameof(MyClass.MyMember);
```

The value of `TypeName` then is `"MyClass"` and the value of `MemberName` then is `"MyMember"`. What do I have to write in F#?

Comment: Looks like it is still being implemented - [F# RFC FS-1003 - nameof Operator](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1003-nameof-operator.md). See also [Discussion thread](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/issues/48)

Comment: nameof is a preview feature starting with F# 4.7

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of F# 4.7, there is a [`nameof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/nameof):

```ml
let months =
    [
        "January"; "February"; "March"; "April";
        "May"; "June"; "July"; "August"; "September";
        "October"; "November"; "December"
    ]

let lookupMonth month =
    if (month > 12 || month < 1) then
        invalidArg (nameof month) ($"Value passed in was %d{month}.")

    months.[month-1]

printfn "%s" (lookupMonth 12)
printfn "%s" (lookupMonth 1)
printfn "%s" (lookupMonth 13)
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, a proper `nameof` operator is work in progress.

In the meantime, you can use F# quotations (similar to C# expression trees) to implement similar functionality - it is a bit uglier and requires some discipline (you need to put actual member access in the quotation), but it at least checks that the member exists and prevents typos:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let nameof (q:Expr<_>) = 
  match q with 
  | Patterns.Let(_, _, DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_, mi, _))) -> mi.Name
  | Patterns.PropertyGet(_, mi, _) -> mi.Name
  | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_, mi, _)) -> mi.Name
  | _ -> failwith "Unexpected format"

let any<'R> : 'R = failwith "!"
```

The `any` definition is just a generic value that you can use to refer to instance members:

```
nameof <@ any<System.Random>.Next @>
nameof <@ System.Char.IsControl @>
```

Comment: That looks like a genuine approach, but I think I will have to wait for the `nameof` operator to be implemented because I need the result to be a compile time constant ( want to use it as an argument for a atttribution). Moreover, am I right that I can only get names of members, but not of types?

Comment: @David - You're right, this is not compile-time constant and you can only get member names (for type names, you'd probably just want `typeof<System.Random>.Name`, but that's the same as in C# - having `nameof` would make that nicer!)

Comment: @TomasPetricek Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119270/continued-is-there-an-equivalent-of-cs-nameof-in-f