# Get name of non-static member in F#

Tags: f#

In C# you can get the name of a method by using

```
nameof(ISomeClass.SomeMethod)
```

Is this doable in F#? When trying to dot into ISomeClass to get the SomeMethod, it merely says "SomeMethod is not a static method"

Comment: Looks like it's the design is approved but not implemented: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1003-nameof-operator.md

Comment: That's good to hear, however it's not just the nameof-operator that's the issue. Even using some of the nameof-workarounds suggested on this site using quotations, I still get the "SomeMethod is not a static method" issue. Essentially it won't let me dot into non-static methods that way at all, like you can in C#.

Comment: You can create a quotation that allows you to get the name of a non-static method interface method.

Comment: I have tried that without success, how do you do it?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a method based around F# quotations that retrieve an interface method in a type-safe manner.

```
open FSharp.Quotations
open FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let getMethodName (e: Expr<'T -> 'U>) = 
  match e with
  | Lambda (_, Call (_, mi, _)) -> mi.Name
  | _ -> failwith "%A is not a valid getMethodName expression, expected Lamba(_ Call(_, _, _))"

type ISomeInterface =
  interface
    abstract SomeMethod: unit -> unit
  end


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let name = <@ fun (i : ISomeInterface) -> i.SomeMethod () @> |> getMethodName
  printfn "%s" name

  0
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you! Upon re-reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304398/is-there-an-equivalent-of-cs-nameof-in-f it appears that it also solves this, you just have to use the any-operator in that answer as well. Either way, two different solutions that work great.

Comment: Similar techniques can be used to find MethodInfos, PropertyInfos, ConstructorInfos as so on. This is doable in C# as well using `Expression`.

Comment: However, if you compare C# `nameof` performance and these quotations based techniques there's a risk there's more overhead of using quotation.